# How do I hide a field using ODOO based on who the user is?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want to hide field from certain users.

I have tried this:

```
   <field name="note_project" attrs="{'invisible': [('members','=',user.id)]}"/>
```

My attempt does not work.

Comment: Set value of user.id

Comment: ex. `<field name="note_project" attrs="{'invisible': [('members','!=',1)]}"/>` , this means visible just for admin

Comment: user.id  this is user ID

Comment: I have already used not work too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Odoo views doesn't carry `user` in context, so you cannot compar it there. This behaviour only applies to access rules. 
Instead you can define inside a model field `is_member`, which computes, whether the given user is a member.

```
is_member = fields.Boolean('Is member', default=False, compute='_compute_is_member')

@api.multi
def _compute_is_member(self):
    for record in self:
        if self.env.uid in record.members:
            record.is_member = True
```

And then change a view:

```
<field name="note_project" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_member','=',True)]}"/>
```